# Сохранить Timestamp в SharedPreferences Android

Tags: java, android, android-shared-preferences, timestamp

Как можно сохранить значение типа `Timestamp` в Shared Preferences?
Насколько я знаю, у Editor есть только методы для `int, string, boolean, long, float`

Comment: Использовать long

Comment: да, timestamp это число типа long, хранящее количество милисекунд от 1 января 1970 года, если речь идет о POSIX-времени/ Поэтому уточните, какой именно формат timestamp используете вы.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно перевести Timestamp в значение типа long, используя метод

```
Timestamp.getTime()
```

и сохранить в Shared Preferences значение типа long. Для обратного преобразования можно использовать конструктор

```
Timestamp (long time)
```

который принимает параметром значение типа long.